Remove Unused Pad/ Via
I want to make remove unused pad/via at inner layer in order to increase area. But I wonder that does it cause problems in terms of IPC Class-III or PCB manufacturing?

Do you mean blind vias?

Ask your manufacturer.

In what software? Most do it automatically on output generation.

I use Altium Designer and Altium Designer doesn`t do automatically on output generation.

Your PCB fabricator can and likely will remove unused inner-layer pads, unless you explicitly tell them otherwise.  They want to do this; each pad is a chance for breakout, and with class III, any breakout is reject.  Talk to your vendor about their default CAM rules and what you would need to specify on your fab drawing to override them.
If you want to remove the pads so that, for example, your planes flood a little better (and you can do so while still maintaining your vendor's minimum clearance from plane to via barrel), you almost certainly need to do that using your layout tool prior to plane processing and output generation.  I'm not familiar with your existing tool, but, if it can't do that, you should find one that can.  That's a pretty standard need.
